# How can i use a backgroundworker and report progress to add items to listBox in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Today now i'm waiting in the backgroundworker dowork event untill all the items to be loaded to the listBox1.
Instead i want to see in real time every item loading to the listBox1.

In the form constructor i'm starting the backgroundworker:

```
backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This is the method where i make the progress report:

```
static List<string> videosList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> videosUrl = new List<string>();
        public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
        {
            UserCredentials();
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                        videosList.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                        videosUrl.Add("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);

                        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);
                    }
                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                   delegate
                   {
                       if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                       {
                           this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                           axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[0];
                       }
                   }));
        }
```

This is the report progress line:

```
backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);
```

In the dowork event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            RetrieveUploadsList();
        }
```

Then in the progress changed event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.UserState);
        }
```

But then i'm getting exception :

This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kirill Shlenskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644813/kirill-shlenskiy) already explained it in general. Let me make it clear. `async/await` is really a replacement of the `BackgroundWorker` and as being such, should not be combined with/used inside `BackgroundWorker`.

Here is the practical example of doing what you described using `async/await`:

First thing to note is that with `async/await` there is no need of thinking for an equivalent of `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerCompleted` event. The usage pattern is like this

```
try
{
    await SomeMethodAsync();
    // Handle here the successful completion
} 
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    // Handle the cancellation here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle the exception here
}
```

For callbacks you can use `IProgress<T>`. It's not limited like the `BackgroundWorker`'s `ProgressChanged` event. As you see, you can specify the type of the data and also you are not limited to just one call. There is a standard implementation class `Progress<T>` which uses the `SynchronizationContext`, effectively marshalling the calls to the UI thread.

Let apply all this to your method. Currently you are providing the callback with a `string`, so the equivalent would be to use `IProgress<string>` for that. So the pure method that does just the work would be something like this

```
private async Task RetrieveUploadsListAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    UserCredentials();
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });

    var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
    channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

    var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
    {
        var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

        Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

        var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
            var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
            playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
            var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
            {
                videosList.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                videosUrl.Add("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);

                progress.Report(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);
            }
            nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we can make the UI aware method like this

```
private async void LoadUploadsListAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var progress = new Progress<string>(text => this.listBox1.Items.Add(text));
        await RetrieveUploadsListAsync(progress);
        if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[0];
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Then remove the `BackgroundWorker` and just call `LoadUploadsListAsync` from the form constructor (or better from form load event).

Comment: Ivan that's working fine. If i want to add somewhere in the LoadUploadsListAsync a Thread.Sleep(100);  I want to make it slower a bit the items add progress. I'm not sure how and where to add the Thread.Sleep(100);

Comment: @SharondohpSharonas In the async world you can use `await Task.Delay(100);` instead

Answer (score 3):

Using async/await inside your `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` handler is a bad idea (as you've learnt the hard way). You can only call `backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress` up to your `await` statement, because the moment you hit `await` the rest of your method will be scheduled as a continuation and the worker will transition to completed state (after that you can't report progress). Immediately after that the thread will move on to other work *before* the rest of your method completes (which is probably not what you expect).

Ditch the background worker and use other async-friendly progress-reporting mechanisms (I recommend `Progress<T>`/`IProgress<T>`) **OR** simply add to the listbox as part of your `RetrieveUploadsList` method (as long as you call it on the UI thread, you can do that).

Comment: Kirill before this way i used invoke inside the RetrieveUploadsList to add to the listBox1 instead doing reportprogress. But then i had to wait untill all items to be loaded before i see them in the listBox and i want to see it in live adding each item and not waiting. I never tried using Progress<T>

Comment: @SharondohpSharonas, this behaviour is expected if you are doing your work synchronously on your UI thread. I am not seeing that in the code you posted, as every time you hit the `await` statement inside your `while (nextPageToken != null)` loop, your UI thread gets a breather and will be able to draw all items added to the list by the previous iteration. Any possibility you were using `playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result` in your tests? Cause that would cause the described problem.
Also, `Invoke` is not necessary if you're calling `RetrieveUploadsList` on the UI thread.